# Проектирование взаимодействия классов

Tags: java, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Проблема в доступе к методам и полям классов. Написав определенный класс (`public class A`) мы хотим получить доступ, к примеру, к его методам из другого класса. Для этого мы создаем экземпляр класса (`A a = new A();`) в классе, в котором хотим получить эти методы:

```
public class B 
{
 A a = new A(); //создание экземпляра
 a.method;      //использование метода
}
```

Но если я хочу получить тот же метод из класса `C`, я должен так же писать в этом класса создание нового экземпляра? Но ведь это будет другой экземпляр, а работать мне нужно с созданным в B классе.

У меня большое количество классов, и все они в той или иной степени связаны между друг другом (получают значения полей, методов) 
Как правильно спроектировать это? Я знаю про синглтон, статик методы и поля, про вложенные классы, но знания эти обрывочные и в целом не помогают. 
Мне нужны примеры, хотя бы абстрактные. Как бы вы сделали, если бы было большое количество классов, и их экземпляры должны были бы между собой взамиодействовать?

Часть моей задачи:
Имеется: 3 класса **детей**(разница в финансах(богатые, средние, бедные), которые реализуют интерфейс(выбор школы и зачисление туда). Класс **школа**, которые имеет поля типа:кол-во мест, классы(9 учеников в 1 классе и т.д.) уровень образования и стоимость, методы(взросление(переход учеников из класса в класс), и выпуск(либо они идут дальше учиться в ср. заведение, либо работать)
Класс **пул школ**(SchoolBoard), в нем просто хранится массив с объектами школ. И класс **Средняя школа**, которая имеет методы как простая школа, только детям при выпуске присваивается специальность. 
Так вот, вопрос казалось бы банальный, но я правда не могу понять очевидный ответ. У меня 3 класса детей и средняя школа должны получать значения полей класса **школа**. К примеру, я написал в одном из классов детей так:

```
public class RichChildren {

SchoolBoard scl = new SchoolBoard();

scl.массивобъектов.гет(2).гетКолвоМест;
...//и тут я спокойно работаю 
}
```

Но, когда мне нужно получить опять те же данные из других классов детей, у меня возникли турдности, как мне этот объект(scl) передать другим классам? 
Я написал так в том же классе детей

```
public SchoolBoard getScl() {
        return scl;
    }
```

но я понимаю, что это не правильно, и более того, чтобы получить этот гет (`getSclb()`), мне нужно создать объект класса детей (`RichChildren`) , чтобы через него уже и использовать метод гет. На этом я и запутался окончательно...

Comment: Наверное многие напишут, что всё зависит от задачи))... Но ведь помимо синглтона есть же еще паттерны проектирования, которые можно применять. Да и не только паттерны.. К примеру можно экземпляр передавать в метод нужный. Например у класса `C` есть метод, который принимает на вход экземпляр класса `A` например `void test(A) { //do smth. }`.....и там работать именно с ним и с его полями

Comment: С большой долей вероятности у вас неправильно спроектировано приложение. Опишите в вопросе подробнее, что из себя представляет класс A, класс В и класс С.

Comment: конечно неправильно, именно по этому я сюда и обратился. 
я жду абстрактных ответов с примерами по возможности. Я написал, что классов много и все связаны друг с другом, поэтому не могу взять и привести пример отдельно взятых классов. В этом то и проблема, что их стало очень много и простое решение типа создания A a = new A();  уже не подходят

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
Спасибо за пример, попробую его использовать)

Comment: Не предоставив конкретных сведений о решаемой вами задаче, вам нельзя посоветовать ничего, кроме как прочитать несколько учебников по проектированию ООП , паттернах проектирования и общей концепции ООП - это очень объемная тема с сотнями (если не тысячами) нюансов и никто здесь не будет раскрывать ее в объеме, достаточном для того, чтобы вы могли решать абстрактные задачи по взаимодействию объектов - понадобятся сотни страниц. В общем случае, объекты не должны иметь никаких прямых связей между собой, каждый должен быть инкапсулирован в решаемой задаче (за исключением объектов-моделей)

Comment: Большой ошибкой будет пытаться прикручивать способы, которые могут использоваться при решении одной задачи, в другую, где это неприемлемо (как передача объекта параметром). Разработка начинается с архитектуры приложения (проектирования), только после того, как станет абсолютно ясно, какие требуются классы для решения всей задачи, как они будут взаимодействовать и тп., можно приступать к написанию собственно кода. Проектирование самый сложный этап и несколькими строчками в комментарии никто вас этому не научит - здесь нужна уверенная база теоретических (и практических) знаний.

Comment: @OgneFF Использовать то - можно пробовать использовать. Но как я сразу написал в начале и как пишет pavloff - все зависит от задачи, от того, что у вас есть и того, что необходимо.

Comment: @pavlofff
Это дельный совет, к которому я не могу не прислушаться. 
Я обновил вопрос с подробным описанием проблемы.
Помоги мне пожалуйста, я уже 5 дней бьюсь над этой ерундой. 
Сейчас нашел паттерн Object pool, думаю может он мне поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это объемная задача, пока не закрыли зарезервирую местечко :)

Сначала очевидное:
 Классы Детей не должны осуществлять выбор и зачисление - для этого вам нужно сделать главный (верхний) класс-администратор на основе структурного шаблона ([паттерн Фасад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))), который и будет осуществлять все действия по управлению Детьми и Школами, в этом классе вы и создаете объекты "подчиненных" классов и манипулируете ими в пределах только этого класса, что избавит вас от связей внутри подчиненных объектов. То есть ни Дети ни Школы не взаимодействуют друг с другом напрямую, а "общаются" через администратора.

Освободится больше времени, попробую дополнить, можете в комментариях уточнить что то непонятное, что раскрыть подробнее.

В качестве бонуса, возможно вам поможет [Шпаргалка по паттернам](http://habrahabr.ru/post/210288/) при дальнейшей разработке.

**UPD**
Немного лирики. Объектно-ориентированное программирование было придумано с целью максимально абстрагироваться от машинной зависимости в сторону человеческих представлений. При разработке вы работаете с объектами, такими же сущностями, что окружают вас повсюду в реальной жизни. Соответственно и в решении задачи отталкивайтесь от реальных примеров из жизни - представьте эту вашу структуру со всеми школами и учениками в них, какой бы она была в реальной жизни. Как она должна существовать.. кто за что отвечает.. как между собой взаимодействует .. и прочие такие вопросы. Распишите это все на бумаге с помощью квадратиков, не стесняйтесь вводить новые должности (какое-нибудь РОНО) если это требуется для организации правильной структуры и тд.

Comment: Да да да)) 
именно такой ответ мне и нужен был :)
спасибо большое :)